# Solr edismax parser and multiple fields search

Tags: search, solr, edismax, dismax

I use the **edismax** query parser to handle user queries against our **Solr 4.10.3** server.

I configured the **q.op** parameter to **AND** and completely disabled the **mm** parameter in order to hit only 100% matches.

When users search for multiple terms in a single field everything works fine.

For example the query **food:(beer cola pizza)** returns only those documents that contains all of the terms **beer**, **cola** and **pizza** in the field **food** which is the expected behaviour.

But when users search in multiple fields Solr seems to forget about the **q.op** configuration and behaves as if the parameter was set to **OR**.

For example the query **food:(beer cola pizza) AND color:(green yellow blue)** returns all those documents that contains one of the terms **beer**, **cola** *OR* **pizza** in the field **food** and those that contains one of the terms **green**, **yellow** *OR* **blue** in the field **color** which isn't the expected behaviour.

A workaround is to explicitely prepare each term with the **+ operator** just like this: **food:(+beer +cola +pizza) AND color:(+green +yellow +blue)**.

But I need to add this operator in our java-webapplication which is kind of a 'hard code' feature. When users decide to configure the **q.op** operator back to **OR** the hard coded **+** would cause problems I think.

Is there a way to reach the expected search results by configuration?

Comment: Would you share the defaults you have specified for that queryhandler from your solrconfig.xml?

Comment: Solr6.3.0 provides edismax with fielded search, If fielded search is not mentioned in qf